# ui-helper-hidden-accessible class in jQuery-UI Dialog wrapper div issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Can someone shed some light on what ui-helper-hidden-accessible jQuery UI CSS class does and how to make it work right or disable? It automatically makes my dialog window invisible. I just commented this class out in jquery-ui.css for now.

Comment: What do you think a class called *hidden*-accessible would do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution might be that you are using a jQuery theme which isn't made for your jQuery \ jQuery-UI-Version. Get a right theme or update the jQuery-js files to the proper version.

Comment: My calendar was not appearing. This was the solution.